# Android lint AnnotationProcessorOnCompilePath with ButterKnife

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, butterknife, android-lint

After upgrading to latest Android gradle plugin:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
```

Android lint (`./gradlew lint`) getting following warning:

> Warning: Add annotation processor to processor path using annotationProcessor instead of implementation [AnnotationProcessorOnCompilePath]
>       implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'

My `app/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
  [...]
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
  kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
}
```

Which is correct according to ButterKnife documentation: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife#download

Hacky solution would be to suppress `//noinspection AnnotationProcessorOnCompilePath` for ButterKnife.

But how to fix this problem properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, it's a bug on Lint side. They say it will be fixed on the upcoming 4.0 release.

Source:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140881211